# VBA: Oracle SQL Insert Query Not Inserting Data

Tags: excel, vba

Apologies if this is too much info, but I wanted to be thorough when posting.

I've been struggling with an issue getting my temporary table to populate with data from an Insert Query.

- This data is being pulled from Oracle SQL tables
- This query creates the temp table, inserts the data, and queries the temp table without issue in the Oracle SQL Developer software
- My code will successfully create the temp table (I've verified its existence in the Oracle software)
- I am able to use Select Queries with my setup (So I do not believe the connection is the issue)
- Running my code doesn't produce any errors (At least nothing that stops the execution)

What I did notice is that if I use "Record Set" in the execution of my insert query, it does show that there are the expected amount of affected rows, but when I Select All (From the Oracle Software) from the temp table it shows nothing populated.

I've been looking all over but I haven't quite figured out what I am missing. From what I was reading it could be that I don't Set NOCOUNT ON (Or Set FEEDBACK OFF), but I can't find how to actually do that within my VBA code. I originally tried inserting the data into an existing table, so I attempted to create a temporary table to move the data into.

Option Explicit

Sub oracleQuery()

```
Dim ws1 As Worksheet
Dim ws2 As Worksheet
Set ws1 = ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets("Query Output")
Set ws2 = ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets("Main Page")
```

Clears query output worksheet

```
ws1.Cells.Clear
```

Assigns variables

```
Dim cnn As New ADODB.Connection
Dim rst As New ADODB.RecordSet
Dim ConnectionString As String
Dim StrQuery As String
Dim StrQuery2 As String
Dim StrQuery3 As String
Dim StrQuery4 As String
```

This query creates a blank Global Temp table (With column headers)

```
StrQuery = "XXXXXX"
```

This is my insert Query

```
StrQuery2 = "INSERT INTO temp_1 (Field1,Field2,Field3,..etc) Select From 
      Where UNION ALL Select From Where UNION ALL..Etc
```

This query selects the data from the temp table, and joins in some addition fields with detail information

```
StrQuery3 = "Select temp_1. Etc....
```

This query is used to drop the temp table when I am done with it

```
StrQuery4 = "DROP TABLE temp_1"
```

This is my connection string

```
ConnectionString = "Provider=OraOLEDB.Oracle;Data Source=(XXX)(CONNECT_DATA=(SERVICE_NAME=XXX)));User ID=XXX;Password=XXX"
```

Opens connection to the database, also sets a timeout timer

```
cnn.Open ConnectionString
cnn.CommandTimeout = 60
```

Executes Temp table query

```
cnn.Execute StrQuery
```

Executes Insert Query

```
cnn.BeginTrans
cnn.Execute StrQuery2
cnn.CommitTrans
```

Executes select query on temp table, uses a record set

```
rst.Open StrQuery3, cnn
```

Drops temp table

```
cnn.Execute StrQuery4
```

Dumps all the results from the record set into cell A2 of the first sheet in the active workbook

```
ws1.Range("A2").CopyFromRecordset rst
```

Empties connection string

```
ConnectionString = ""
```

Closes and clears recordset

```
rst.Close
Set rst = Nothing
```

End Sub

It would be great to determine what is actually causing my Insert Query to not insert data. I would greatly appreciate any insight on this issue as I am running out of ideas to check.

***UPDATE*** I simplified my code to hone in on my problem. My issue is the INSERT INTO Query is not actually inserting any data into the table. The Select Query I am trying to Insert results in 3 columns & rows of data.

Temp table query

```
StrQuery = "CREATE GLOBAL TEMPORARY TABLE temp_1( GALOTIDX Number(9, 0), LOTID VARCHAR2(12 BYTE), LOTDESCR VARCHAR2(40 BYTE))"
```

INSERT INTO Query String

```
StrQuery2 = "Insert INTO temp_1 (GALOTIDX, LOTID, LOTDESCR)"
StrQuery2 = StrQuery2 + " Select LotIdx, ID1, Descr1 From DataTable1"
```

Query For Final Select

```
StrQuery3 = "Select * From temp_1"
```

Query for Dropping Temp Table

```
StrQuery4 = "DROP TABLE temp_1"
```

Builds connection string

```
ConnectionString = "Provider=OraOLEDB.Oracle;Data Source=(DESCRIPTION=(ADDRESS=(PROTOCOL=TCP)(Host=XXX)(Port=XXX))(CONNECT_DATA=(SERVICE_NAME=XXX)));User ID=XXX;Password=XXX"
```

Opens connection to the database, also sets a timeout timer

```
cnn.Open ConnectionString
cnn.CommandTimeout = 60
```

Creates Temp Table

```
cnn.Execute StrQuery
```

Executes Insert Into Query

```
Dim recordsAffected As Integer

cnn.BeginTrans
cnn.Execute StrQuery2, recordsAffected
cnn.CommitTrans
```

Selects Data from temp table and dumps into a worksheet

```
rst.Open StrQuery3, cnn
ws1.Range("A2").CopyFromRecordset rst
```

Drops Temp Table

```
cnn.Execute StrQuery4
```

Empties connection string

```
ConnectionString = ""
cnn.Close
```

Comment: I believe temp table are per-session visible only, so you cannot see the contents from a different session than the one used to create it.  The issue may be that you're closing and then re-opening the connection before trying to read the data.

Comment: When executing my code line by line, I checked (The Oracle Software) after the temp table query was ran and I saw it was created, and when I ran the query to drop the temp table, I could see that it was dropped. My interpretation was that if I could see the creation and drop, I should have been able to see if data was inserted. Also, the select query in my code didn't pick anything up either. Am I missing something with the connection throughout the code?

Comment: TBH what you posted isn't comprehensive enough to really know what's going on - it's not clear if you carried out all of the steps in succession using a single connection, or if you didn't.  It might be helpful to create a very stripped-down example which you can post in its entirety but which still shows the same issues.   Set NOCOUNT ON and Set FEEDBACK OFF are more like SQLPLus commands and I've never used them outside of that tool.

Comment: What would be helpful to show? More details on the Insert Query? My issue is that the Insert Query is Massive. The contents of it seem fairly simple, it is comprised of a handful of Select Queries with unions between each of them. On its own it function properly. What focal point should I use when posting more detail?

Comment: I guess something simple - like a hard-coded temp table insert of a single row, which you can query right out again to show that the basic approach is sound?  And show the full code for that.

Comment: Just added the simplified detail above

Comment: All I see you doing in the simplified example is creating a temporary table, adding records, and then dropping it?  Where's the part where you try to query out the records you just inserted?  FYI if you think there may be errors which for some reason are not being surfaced, you can try looking at the `Connection.Errors` property after each step   https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/167957/info-extracting-error-information-from-ado-in-vb

Comment: I just updated my code again to reflect that. I removed it because I was watching the Oracle Software for table updates. Something I did notice (Added Above) was that If i added a variable to the recordselected property in the .Execute function, the variable is given the value 3 (Expected number of records). I did previously try to use the Connection.Errors property but wasn't coming up with any errors, I'll read through the link and see if I did anything incorrectly.

Comment: And `StrQuery3` returns zero records?  One thing to try is remove the transaction lines - you do not need them here I think.

Comment: The default behavior for a a temp table is "on commit delete rows", so that's likely your problem.   https://docs.oracle.com/javadb/10.8.3.0/ref/rrefdeclaretemptable.html

Comment: Yeah StrQuery3 Doesn't dump anything into the worksheet. If I remove the INSERT INTO and just use the Query as a Select Query, the results are dumped onto the worksheet. Just tried removing the transaction lines and it didn't seem to change anything. Another thing a read was that the INSERT INTO was being messed with by the SQL Message "XX Rows Added". I'm not sure if that is the issue though

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looks like your `commit` may be deleting your rows.

From:  https://docs.oracle.com/javadb/10.8.3.0/ref/rrefdeclaretemptable.html

> ON COMMIT Specifies the action taken on the global temporary table
>   when a COMMIT operation is performed.
>
> DELETE ROWS All rows of the table will be deleted if no hold-able
>   cursor is open on the table. **This is the default value for ON COMMIT**.
>   If you specify ON ROLLBACK DELETE ROWS, this will delete all the rows
>   in the table only if the temporary table was used. ON COMMIT DELETE
>   ROWS will delete the rows in the table even if the table was not used
>   (if the table does not have hold-able cursors open on it).
>
> PRESERVE ROWS The rows of the table will be preserved.

Comment: Tim I really appreciate you effort in helping me out with this issue. Adding "ON COMMIT PRESERVE ROWS" at the end of my Temp Table Creation Query solved the issue I was having. Thank-you!